# Centered, responsive, scaling CSS3 triangle not sticking to div below it

Tags: css, shapes

I've taken code for a CSS3 triangle and modified it so it stays centered when the screen is resized as well as scaling itself, which is the desired behavior.  However, on wider size displays, there is a gap between the triangle and the div below it.  The triangle and 2 divs below it are all part of a footer, so they need to stay together with no gaps in between.  Please see my jsFiddle and the code below.  Does anyone see how to modify it so that even on a wide display, the red triangle always touches the red div below it?  I prefer a pure CSS solution if possible.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hcpjhme5/) - Widen the results frame to see the gap that grows between the triangle and the div below it.

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfjSD.jpg)

HTML:

```
<footer>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div id = "footer-top"><h1>Footer Heading</h1></div>
  <div id = "footer-bottom"></div>
 </footer>
```

CSS:

```
.triangle {
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  padding-left:50%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:block;
  margin:0px auto;
}

.triangle:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left:-400px;
  border-left: 400px solid transparent;
  border-right: 400px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #FF0000;
}

#footer-top,
#footer-bottom {
  background:#FF0000;
  min-height:200px;
}

#footer-top h1 {
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#FFF;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0px;
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Note: The triangle is this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcpjhme5/2/) works perfectly as described above, however it's an equilateral triangle, and  I'm trying to achieve this same effect with a short but wide triangle.

Comment: I tried it on a MacBook Pro, and it works as expected. Please share a screenshot if possible.

Comment: I added a screenshot link to the original post.  Also, I see that in my fiddle I forgot the closing </h1> tag, but adding that doesn't make a difference.